# Crontab with Github

Tags: debian, cron, git, repository, github

I want to be able to push a repository to Github at midnight, every night. I know that Github isn't a back-up service, and, in no way am I expecting it to be this - I just want the best up-to-date version on Github and this works for me, and, my team. What I was thinking is this:

- Creating a Bash script that pushes the repository to Github normally
- In Crontab, execute the script at midnight every day of the week.

Would this be the best method to use? If so, this seems easy enough to do.

My next problem :) I want an email to be sent to me, after the repository has been pushed, so it would just send an email saying: "Repository Pushed.. Ok" or if there was a problem, it would alert me to this. Is this possible? If so, could anyone please provide some examples of how to do this.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/264710/how-do-i-create-a-cron-job-that-will-commit-my-project-changes-to-git-on-a-weekl) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35466/how-to-perform-git-push-using-crontab) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the links described as harish.venkat

Create a script `/path_to_script`, which would add new file, commit and push.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /location/of/clone

git add *
if [[ $? != 0 ]] then 
   mail -s "add failed" someone@some.com
   exit 1
fi

git commit -a -m "commit message, to avoid being prompted interactively"
if [[ $? != 0 ]] then 
   mail -s "commit failed" someone@some.com
   exit 1
fi

git push
if [[ $? != 0 ]] then 
   mail -s "push failed" someone@some.com
   exit 1
fi

mail -s "push ok" someone@some.com
```

Change the script to executable,

```
chmod a+x /path_to_script
```

Use `crontab -e` and add below line

```
 # run every night at 03:00
 0 3 * * * /path_to_script
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is actually what I need. Is it possible to have multiple .git repositories updated? E.g. if I had a folder called "Repositories" on the server which contained multiple .git repositories update everynight? If that makes sense..

Comment: Why not? You can setup anther scripte with updated `/location/of/clone`.

Comment: Does this imply that for each of the repositories I have to create a new script?

Comment: If you are novice in shell scripting, it would be better to setup a new script.